# R - Exact String Match - Revisited

Tags: r, regex

I have the below test input in a file called Input

```
Exploratory objectives :    

This is Exp objective 1

This is Exp objective 2

3.3 Exploratory objective(s) 

This is Exp objective 1   

This is Exp objective 2
```

From this text file, I'm trying to grep for "Exploratory objective(s)" using the below. The output line number I am expecting is 7.

However, when I run the below command: I am getting the line number as 1. Can anyone please point out what is wrong with my grep here and why it doesnt return 7? Also how I can fix this?

```
 key_str <-"Exploratory objective(s)"  
 key_str 
 key_pat <- paste0("(", key_str, ")", "(?![[:alpha:]])")
 line_number<-grep(key_pat,Input,perl=TRUE)
 line_number

 Expected line_number: 7

 Output line_number using above: 1 (Incorrect)
```

Comment: You mean line_number 4, not 7, right?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for  your response. I meant line_number 7 counting the empty lines as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape parentheses:

```
key_str <- "Exploratory objective\\(s\\)"
```

If the string is dynamically generated or read from a file, use this:

```
key_str <- gsub("([\\(\\)])", "\\\\\\1", string)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This works if I have the string as-is. But if I read the string "Exploratory objective(s)" dynamically from a file or otherwise into a variable, any idea how I can escape the "("?